# How to tell what user has synced

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication

I have set up merge replication web sync to sync a publication from a SQL Server 2012 database.

I am trying to make some parameterised filters using `SUSER_SNAME()` or `HOST_NAME()`.

When I do a sync is it possible to find somewhere what the values of `SUSER_SNAME()` and `HOST_NAME()` actually were for that sync? E.g. in the system tables.

I will need to experiment with security to work out what settings will affect these values, but I will need to find out what these values actually are to verify my settings.

Comment: I don't believe SQL Server tracks this by default. You could likely set something up to do it going forward using extended events (or trace).

Answer (score 0):

Not really anything obvious.

The easiest would be if you have a backup you could restore to view it.

Otherwise you'll properly try - either yourself, daunting, or via commercial tools to find a tool that lets you explore the transaction log for the given changes.
For example something like: http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx

I've not tried out such tools myself so I cannot vouch for them. 
I usually get by either by having backups to search, or in some cases, I've set up change tables to log changes to critical data.